# VBScript for starting queued COM+ apps - leaking memory

Tags: com, vbscript, com+

I have a simple VBScript that's iterating through all COM+ apps and starting the ones that are queued. This runs every half hour. My server has 2.5gb of memory. Then after about 3 full days of this, I get an "Out of memory" error from Windows Script Host. However, it seems the server memory is fine. Around 1gb free.

This is what my script looks like;

```
dim cat 
Dim apps
Dim app

set cat = CreateObject ("COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog") 

set apps = cat.getcollection("Applications")
apps.populate

for each app in apps
  if app.Value("QueuingEnabled") then
    cat.StartApplication (app.name) 
  end if
next
```

Last time I got this error it reported line #7; `set apps = cat.getcollection("Applications")` as the place it ran out of memory. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this problem? I have very little experience with COM+, so it's hard for me to see what's consuming memory here. There are only about 8 COM+ apps running on the server, and they are not at all large.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
Set app = Nothing
Set apps = Nothing
Set cat = Nothing
```

at the end of your script.

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304713 for an example of how to use the COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog object.

Comment: I just found out I had let "procmon" running, that's what it was. The 'nothing' declarations are good habits though, I'll give you the answer here :]

Comment: See Eric Lippert's [When Are You Required To Set Objects To Nothing?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/04/28/122259.aspx) for an interesting dicussion on the `Set var = Nothing` practice.  The surprising answer is: almost never.